# Android app does not shown in tablets

Tags: android, google-play

I developed the app to support all android mobiles and tablets... 
I created the layouts for **mobile:**

```
layout-hdpi
layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-xhdpi
```

**For 7 inch Tablets:**

```
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw600dp-land
```

**For 10 inch Tablets:**

```
layout-sw800-xlarge-mdpi
layout-sw800-xlarge-land-mdpi
```

**Manifest details:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I used the camera and call function. The uses permission given in manifest. Am i missing any other permission for camera and call function???

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Yesterday i uploaded the app in google play... when i add the screen for seven inch it mentioned **You uploaded the screen shot for 7 inch tablets but your apk does not seem to be designed for 7 inch tablet.**.

Please suggest what are the changes in my layout and manifest details....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I publish the app in google store. Now the app supported in tablets. I include the target sdk version in manifest.

**Manifest Details:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I used camera and call function in my app. Camera and sim options are not available in some tablets. so hardware user features must be added to manifest.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

from the manifest.
I have uploaded multiple apks to the Play Store and they work on all devices but I have never used supports-screens in the Manifest.
It could be that there is another field which you need to include which default is false.

Comment: am using camera and call funtion. i mentioned the uses permission in above code. am i missing any other uses permission or uses feature for using camera and call function???

Comment: no i don't think so. have you tried just removing the supports-screens from the manifest?